# issue uploading media files on /media whatsapp cloud api

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, codeigniter-4, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am trying to upload a file through WhatsApp Cloud API so, I am using a simple cURL request to do it.

```
public function meta_upload_media2($token,$phonesid,$tipo,$archivo,$filename)
    {        

        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/'.$phonesid.'/media';

        $fileFinal=new \CURLFile($archivo,$tipo,$filename);
        
        $data = array(
            'file' => $fileFinal,
            'type' => $tipo,
            'messaging_product' => 'whatsapp'
        );
        $headers = array(); 
        
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
        $result = curl_exec($ch);        

        if($result === false) {
            $result = curl_error($ch) . " - ".curl_errno($ch);
            //return false;
            
        }else{
            $resultDecode = json_decode($result);
            if($resultDecode!=null){
                $result = $resultDecode;
            }
            return($result);
            //return true;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

I am unable to upload the file, I got the following error:

> "error": {
> "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 1,
> "fbtrace_id": "ActSWlPfhEOVpbiN2QmIf7X"
> }

FYI:
** I am on CI4 and PHP 8.1
** $filename is a random filename
** $archivo is a full path file, ex. /home/user/public_html/uploads/random-file-name.pdf

Any help is really appreciate.
Thanks!

Comment: We don't know what parameters you are calling `meta_upload_media2` with, so we can't currently tell if what you supply for `type` etc., makes any sense.

Comment: I tried type as "image" also mime type but nothing happens.  Same if I tried with "audio" or "video" as type same issue with corresponding mime type

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the following code

```
$ch = curl_init();
        $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/'.$phonesid.'/media';
        
        $data = array(
            'file' => new \CURLFile($archivo,$type),
            'type' => $type,
            'messaging_product'=>'whatsapp'
        );
        $headers = array(); 
        
        $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token ;
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: multipart/form-data';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
        $result = curl_exec($ch);        

        if($result === false) {
            $result = curl_error($ch) . " - ".curl_errno($ch);
            //return false;
            
        }else{
            $resultDecode = json_decode($result);
            if($resultDecode!=null){
                $result = $resultDecode;
            }
            return($result);
            //return true;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).